# JSON hijack injection - best practices for avoidance - & which browsers are vulnerable?

Tags: javascript, xml, json, security

What are the best methods to securing a json response?

We do address verification that is a response back from a web service in json format. We would like to secure that response.

There are a few mentions, using a "while(1)" to cause an infinite loop and I'm curious to know of other tried and true methods.

Based on:
http://lab.gsi.dit.upm.es/semanticwiki/index.php/JSON_Hijacking_%28aka_JavaScript_Hijacking%29

http://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/111.html

***UPDATE***

Ok, a more specific question may be which browsers are vulnerable to this type of injection?

and is returning json over ssl and making sure it's correct syntax (not just an array) enough of a security safeguard?

Comment: What is your question? Or are you asking about a general subject of javascript inject (XSS).

Comment: Please ask a specific question. Dumping two links is not a question.

Comment: @Jason you should start by describing what problem you are having :-)

Comment: Is it just me, or is that first linked article describing JSONP instead of JSON? Actual JSON data isn't requested via a `<script>` tag. If it is, then it's a JSONP request, and the response isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @amnotiam: I think the issue is: you have an AJAX call (`http://example.com/get_account`) that returns JSON.  What if I make a site with `<script id="json" src="http://example.com/get_account"></script>`, and make you click on it while logged in?  BAM, I have your JSON (`$('#json').html()`), and I'm sending it to my server :-P

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: What's that? :-P

Comment: @Rocket http://alphapersona.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/not-sure-if-joking-or-serious.png

Comment: @Rocket: I see what you're saying, but I didn't realize that was possible. When I do `$('script').eq(0).html()` on this page, I get an empty string.

Comment: @amnotiam: Guess you can't do that then.

Comment: @Rocket `SCRIPT` either refers to a script file or contains the script itself. But it cant’t/doesn’t do both.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the code at https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/blob/master/lib/xss.js.  I've found it to be pretty thorough in the types of checks it does to prevent xss type attacks.

Comment: Nice counter attack by answer a question with just two links with an answer of just a link.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to prevent such an attack (if I understood your question right) is the following:

Prevent the cookies to be avialable to javascript. When setting a cookie in PHP you have the option to prevent this:

```
setcookie ('cookie_name', 'value', 1200, '/path', 'www.example.com', true, true);
```

Where the last true means not accessible by javascript.

Besides protecting from your cookie being stolen you should ALWAYS use [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection.

This can [be done](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) be generating a random token and only allow request done using that random token.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstand. deleted.